# What software do i need to replicate the effect in this video

Tags: video

i would like to replicate the same type of graphics that are used  10 seconds into the video. I have after effects but i'm unsure of the process.

Comment: I wish people who downvote a question would at least comment with a reason.

Comment: yes...its an honest question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to match the terrain and camera move like in the video? Then you'll need to make a 3D model of the terrain and overlay that 3D layer.

**If you have not shot your location footage**

1. Optionally begin by laying some markers down on your location shoot.
2. Optional pro-tip for advanced VFX: Note camera, lens, aperture, focus length (for DOF) so you can build your virtual camera.
3. Use After Effects 3D camera tracker to overlay your lines.

**If you have already shot location footage.**

1. Use After Effects 3D camera tracker to overlay your lines.

If you want a simpler effect, without the 3D and a simpler camera move, you could use a google map or other 2D picture top down. Your lines would then be just an animated layer over the top of a picture shot with a fake camera move - like a rostrum camera for documentaries.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that in after effect. You need first to make these kind of animations and then convert them to 3D layers and place them where you want. Or wice versa.

Comment: You could improve your answer by expanding a little on *how* you would do this.